# Unable to get correct output from a function

Tags: python

I am developing an app. In that there are certain fields where only numerical input is allowed. Now in python we can give `int(input())` but if the user passes a non-numerical value, it quits and says `ValueError`. But I need the program to prompt the user to enter a correct input until he gives the correct one (think of a `while` loop).
Now I am giving in a code snippet from my main program. I think I have done things correctly but it doesnt work.

Here is the code:

```
def intsytaxcheck(intvar, inputstatement):
    try:
        intvar = int(input(inputstatement))
        return intvar
    except ValueError:
        print("Only integers (1,43,532) are allowed!")
        intsytaxcheck(intvar, inputstatement)
        return intvar

a = ''
a = intsytaxcheck(a,"Enter Rollnum: ")
print(a)
```

Now the `intvar` param remains unchanged. I tried giving `return intvar` at the indentation of the function block.

i.e., Like this:

```
    try:
        intvar = int(input(inputstatement))
    except ValueError:
        print("Only integers (1,43,532) are allowed!")
        intsytaxcheck(intvar, inputstatement)
    return intvar
```

What should I do here?

Comment: Recursion isn't really the right way in this case, but `intvar` is passed by value, and not by reference, so its value is not being modified. Inside the except clause, just do `return intsyntaxcheck(...)`. Actually, there is no need for a `intvar` parameter in this function.

Comment: Are `1, 43, 532` examples of integers? Or the integers that can only be accepted by the code?

Comment: @12944qwerty yes it is examples of integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:

```
def intsytaxcheck(inputstatement):
    try:
        return int(input(inputstatement))
    except ValueError:
        print("Only integers (1,43,532) are allowed!")
        return intsytaxcheck(inputstatement)

print(intsytaxcheck("Enter Rollnum: "))
```

result:

```
Enter Rollnum: a
Only integers (1,43,532) are allowed!
Enter Rollnum: b
Only integers (1,43,532) are allowed!
Enter Rollnum: 1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `while loop`

```
def intsytaxcheck(intvar, inputstatement):
    while True:
        intvar=input(inputstatement)
        if intvar.isdigit(): #=== Check is input is a digit
            return intvar
        else:
            print("Only integers (1,43,532) are allowed!")
```

Or you can change your `except` method:

```
except ValueError:
    print("Only integers (1,43,532) are allowed!")
    return intsytaxcheck('', inputstatement)
```

Comment: Welcome @AkashSVidhyaniketan

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop seems to be more understandable than recursion. Also, `intvar` parameter is not needed as enzo mentioned. By the way, you misspelled `syntax` to `sytax`.

```
def intsyntaxcheck(inputstatement):
    while True:
        try:
            intvar = int(input(inputstatement))
            return intvar
        except ValueError:
            # I deleted the part of (1, 43, 532),
            # you can add a if statement to restrict choice if you want
            print("Only integers are allowed!")

a = intsyntaxcheck("Enter Rollnum: ")
print(a)
```

Output:

```
Enter Rollnum: a
Only integers are allowed!
Enter Rollnum: 1
1
```

Comment: So does the `return intvar` breaks the while loop?

Comment: @AkashSVidhyaniketan `return` statement will break the loop.